# Reduce data by taking averages

Tags: vector

I am trying to implement the following:

I have got two vectors `x` and `y` of unequal lengths. The length of `y` is much larger than `x`.

I want to define a new `y` such that its length will be equal to the length of `x` by taking appropriate averages of the elements in `y`. For example, if `y` includes 200 elements and `x` 100 elements, then I would define a new `y` such that `y` will be the average of every subsequent two elements in `y`.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that the lengths of the lists are integer multiples of each other, you could do this:

```
x = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 100];
y = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 200];

Mean /@ Partition[y, Length[y]/Length[x]]

(*
==> {37/2, 79, 23, 58, 111/2, 59, 143/2, 45/2, 51, 123/2, 57, \
76, 43, 111/2, 93/2, 33, 97/2, 37/2, 51, 151/2, 43, 7/2, 191/2, \
123/2, 44, 49, 68, 129/2, 137/2, 121/2, 99/2, 85/2, 81/2, 77/2, 73, \
179/2, 129/2, 36, 51, 135/2, 95/2, 63, 71, 31, 91, 36, 49, 43/2, 80, \
23, 51, 123/2, 59, 54, 37, 123/2, 57, 81/2, 115/2, 123/2, 121/2, \
103/2, 129/2, 39, 91/2, 46, 85, 53/2, 43/2, 83, 71, 24, 27, 66, 47/2, \
52, 113/2, 97/2, 57/2, 71, 68, 48, 22, 129/2, 103/2, 141/2, 45/2, \
123/2, 30, 131/2, 45, 83, 74, 18, 79/2, 115/2, 29, 113/2, 59, 66}
*)
```

If the lengths aren't divisible, you can do this:

```
With[{n = Floor[Length[y]/Length[x]]}, 
 Mean /@ Partition[PadRight[y, n Length[x], Last[y]], n]]
```

which adjusts the size of `y` before partitioning it.

Above, you can replace `Floor` by `Ceiling` or `Round`, depending on how you want to handle cases where the lengths are mismatched. The `PadRight` doesn't have to be changed, though. If the partitioned list is too short, it will cut off the right-most element(s), otherwise it will add the last element until the desired length is reached.

Following rcollyer's comment, one could also do something like this:

```
Needs["Developer`"]

With[{n = Floor[Length[y]/Length[x]]}, 
 PartitionMap[Mean, PadRight[y, n Length[x], Last[y]], n]]
```

This combines two steps of my first approach into one command, [`PartitionMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Developer/ref/PartitionMap.html).

Comment: You might be better off with `Ceiling[Length[y]/Length[x]]]` rather than `Floor[ ]`, because if you end up with 0 length in the `Partition`, you will get an error.

Comment: I'd use ``Developer`PartitionMap`` for this, as it applies the function as it is partitioning the list. It tends to be a bit faster. The signature is ``Developer`PartitionMap[f_, partitionargs__]``.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for the alternative - it's documented under the `Developer` package, but it was new to me.

Comment: Since at least v8 (maybe in v7, too), ``Developer` `` has been accessible without resorting to `Needs`, but only by fully qualifying the name. So, `Needs` here puts ``Developer` `` onto the `$ContextPath`, but nothing more. :)

Comment: @rcollyer Neat, `Needs` ain't needed...

Comment: and, useful, as the packing constructs are also directly accessible.

Answer (score 8):

As I interpret the question I recommend that you use `Interpolation` for this due to its versatility and configurability.

Here is some example data:

```
x = Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 7 Pi, 7 Pi/99}];
y = Table[Cos[x], {x, 0, 7 Pi, 7 Pi/236}];
{lnx, lny} = Length /@ {x, y}
```

> {100, 237}

Now create a mapping and plot it:

```
yint = Interpolation[y, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

y2 = yint @ Rescale[Range@lnx, {1, lnx}, {1, lny}];

ListLinePlot[{x, y2}]
```

[image]